# Is flagging now being a long queue in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, status-declined, flags, moderators

Does flag queue is now very long on Stack Overflow?

As an example, where a moderator has said the flag queue is very long <s>on his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239627/make-content-store-use-database-in-symfony-cmf#comments-11239627)</s>. The comment post is removed as part of moderation. I am attaching an image of post. You can view the comment in attached image.

Are there any plans to increase the number of moderators on Stack Overflow?

[image: post]

Comment: "Currently SO have only 4 moderators" - um... look again, there's 16 of them. And no, 265 flags atm isn't a lot for SO. I've seen it above 700.

Comment: Is that actually true? I've never had a wait time of a year - all my mod flags have been decided within a week. If it's true, though, that's frightening.

Comment: I agree that the flag queue is very long and need more attention

Comment: Flag well. Those with a good flag history get attention fairly quickly. Look on it as motivation.

Comment: @Mystical Some of them have diamonds, but they don't serve as moderators the same way an elected or a pro-tem moderator does.

Comment: @JustinJohn What are you talking about? I regularly see all of them active in the flag queue. They all serve as active moderators.

Comment: @Mystical Can you please post a link where it shows current moderators?

Comment: @JustinJohn The 16 moderators are shown in Manishearth's answer. As a 10k user, I can see them deleting posts from the flag queue. Some more often than others, but I do actually see all of them.

Comment: @JustinJohn: http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: @Knights: He's saying that the question itself took 1 year to close. The longest we've ever had a single flag remain pending was a couple of weeks.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: That could be it. In that case, however, I doubt the _flag_ was active for so long. I've flagged plenty of old posts myself.

Comment: SO recently had 4 mods elected, that's different from having 4 elected moderators.

Comment: Why this post is downvoted this much? My point of total number of moderators is wrong, but number of moderator 4 or 16 still not relevant here as flaq queue is very long with current number of moderator(16).

Comment: Everyone tend to answer as count of moderator is not correct. I think, most guys doesn't check rest of question. It may happens that some points in post may be wrong, but it doesn't means whole post is wrong. We normally catch with that single wrong point leave the rest of post as wrong. Try to give response as of whole post, not by single point present in post.

Comment: The down-votes are from users that probably think there is no need to add new moderators to handle the flag queue. Your question is then based on two misunderstandings: the number of Stack Overflow moderators, and the average time taken to handle a flag.

Comment: Yeah, what kiamlaluno said. Downvotes on meta sites indicate disagreement, and I suppose most people disagree that more SO moderators are needed. (Though the fact that you used incorrect information about the number of current moderators and their statuses, and stuck to that information for some time even after people corrected you, probably didn't help.)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky You mean, I need to edit my question immediately after the people corrected the incorrect information about the number of current moderators and their statuses.

Comment: Like I said, I don't _know_ if you got downvotes because of that, I'm just trying to think of possible causes. It's not that you need to edit immediately, but commenting "Can you please post a link where it shows current moderators?" comes across as though you don't believe there are 16 moderators. (Sure, that's probably not what you meant, but it's easy to misinterpret things online and _some_ people are not so forgiving.) And what does "Some of them have diamonds, but they don't serve as moderators the same way an elected or a pro-tem moderator does" mean? (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Basically, all this stuff makes people wonder whether you did any research to figure out how many moderators there are, and more importantly, whether you reconsidered your research after you were told that you had the wrong number. People on Stack Exchange _really_ don't appreciate askers who don't do appropriate prior research. But honestly, I think **that's a minor contribution**. I bet every person who downvoted this question disagrees that more moderators are needed, and that is the primary reason you're getting downvoted.

Comment: You shouldn't significantly change a question that already has answers. I'd suggest you roll this change back and create a new question with your new (support) input instead.

Comment: @AndersUP I am forced to do it. The problem is, I can't ask any more questions due to heavy down votes. If I need to regain the asking rights, this post needs to have less down votes or need to be upvoted by other community members. As I have asked this post earlier as feature request, it will never going to less the downvotes in earlier form. So I tried to change the status `feature request` to `support` to minimize the downvotes. What else I can do?

Comment: **I have a request to all community members**
When a feature request is posted in meta sites, probably it get downvotes to indicate disagreement for that feature request.
It never says the post is bad. But the downvotes that can be accumulate for that will end up OP's asking rights. She can't ask any more questions and will be out of this world. 
So friends, Please consider this in mind before downvoting a post.

Comment: I see your problem, but the suggestion to edit your vote and improve your post does not mean to change it completely, **especially** if it has answers. Normally, I'd vote down a question for that reason alone, because it invalidates the answers given. You have basically changed your question from "Are there plans to increase number of moderators, four are too few" to "Is the flag queue very long?", making @Manisheart and Annas answers nonsensical.

Comment: @AndersUP I have added that part to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it really isn't. The four new moderators have been extremely active, to the point where many times I visit the site during the day now and see very little for me to handle. I believe the flag queue has been depleted more times since the last election than the year before that. The average flag handling time has decreased from 7 hours to 5 to under 2 hours this weekend.

Every single elected or appointed moderator has been active over the last month, although we come and go as personal and work needs draw us away. I was off at a scientific conference for three days this week, for example, but I'm not sure people even noticed.

The queue still spikes from time to time on weekends or overnight U.S.-time due to fewer moderators being around then, but that's usually whittled down within an hour or two. I think we have a reasonably sustainable number of moderators for the traffic we should see for the next year or so.

It's also important to note that we act on flags in order of importance, so even when the flag queue is large, we can still take action on spam or trolling within minutes. Lower-priority flags like those for close votes can wait while we take care of other things.

Answer (score 19):

Four? SO has *sixteen* mods right now. Dunno how many are active, but from what I see in TL *at least* 10 are active. Most probably all of them.

[image]

Will's comment about flags was tongue in cheek. The flag queue does get large at times (or so I've heard), but not *that* large.

Comment: You mean including pro-tem moderator also. But still my question increase moderators still revelant.

Comment: @JustinJohn Stack Overflow doesn't have pro-tem moderators: The site is already out of beta phase from ages.

Comment: Some of them have diamonds, but they don't serve as moderators the same way an elected or a pro-tem moderator does.

Comment: What the heck is the "punch" option? :P Do you really hate the mods that much?

Comment: @JustinJohn: What? No. "Appointed" doesn't necessarily mean pro tem. Pro tem is only for a beta sites, the mod team is elected afresh when a site graduates. For SO, the situation is special -- there are appointed mods but they don't have a limited term.

Comment: @JustinJohn: They are all elected/appointed and have the same duties. What you're thinking of are devs/community team members -- they aren't listed here.

Comment: @Mysticial: http://stackapps.com/questions/3802/punch-a-user-button

Comment: @Manishearth You have too much time on your hands. :)

Comment: @Mysticial: I think someone (in chat) mentioned that we should have a way to punch people, and I modified balpha's script to make this. It's really a 5-minute job, the only parts I wrote are at the bottom of the script.

Comment: @kiamlaluno SO never was in beta. SO came before A51

Comment: @Luke: Yes, but the concept of a beta precluded A51. SO had a private beta where you had to enter a secret password to get in. (AFAICT, no other SE1.0 site had a beta)

Comment: Wow. I didn't know that. Was it called beta at the time?

Comment: @Luke There are 2522 users with the [Beta](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/30/beta) badge. Surely the concept of beta site existed before Area 51. :)

Comment: @Luke: Yeah, it was. IIRC the password was shared in certain mailing groups and other places. Note that this was before Meta (they had a forum called UserVoice back then, and nothing has been migrated over)

Answer (score 4):

We ran a moderator election relatively recently, so currently we have no plans to have another one any time soon.

Maybe next year... but we'd really rather spend more time making it easier for the moderators to do their job. Just throwing more moderators at the site again and again isn't going to scale.